# Processing working only on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, processing

I'm working on a website in HTML5 CSS3 but I can't make my processing sketch work on other browsers than firefox.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>  
        <title>Project</title>
        <script type="javascript" src="processing.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas data-processing-sources="accueil.pde"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried with CSS and without (this is only html code with an inclusion of Processing sketch into) and it only work on mozilla firefox.

Comment: If you want our help you should provide your code, we will do your work for you and code a finished solution for you. Show us your code and somebody will take a look at it and point you in the right direction.

Comment: What does your JavaScript console say? What exactly do you mean when you say it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering if someone have the same error than me:
Processing sketchs work only in firefox browser if you're in localhost.
If you want to try it on other browser you need to host your website.